# "Jimmy did his homework and so didn't his brother" Is this correct?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, american-english

Shouldn't it be "...***and so did*** his brother"?  I got confused when I read the original sentence in an American newspaper some time ago. It read something like this:

> "US Representative from Massachusetts Jimmy McGovern voted for the Higher Educational Act **and so didn't** Bill Keating."

Misprints do happen and I shouldn't be surprised if this were the case. The phrase was used twice, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong in standard English.

It's used regionally in the U.S.; [see this webpage](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/so-dont-i). The webpage says it's used in Eastern New England (it also appears in DeKalb county, Illinois, which was settled by New Englanders). it means *"so did I"*.

Comment: Good link, thanks. It must cause some confusion. I wonder how it came to be used since it seems to mean exactly the opposite. To me it's just like asking "Have you been to Mary's?" and getting "yes, I haven't" for an answer.

Comment: What an utterly bizarre construction. I have never seen or heard that before, and I’m fairly certain I’d notice, given how bewilderingly illogical and unintuitive it is. I wonder if perhaps it has something to do with the Hibernian English phenomenon of using interrogative construction in these kinds of consecutive _and_ statements (“McGovern voted for it, and didn’t Bill Keating just do so, too?”), somehow muddled up with the more standard “and so [aux] [subj]” construction …

Comment: @Janus: I know I've seen or heard it, but not very often. I live near Boston, which is close to Maine (which the webpage says is the part of "Eastern New England" this expression is most common).

Comment: I live in Vermont (Western New England) and this is pretty common here, too.

Comment: If it's wrong in standard English, and that particular construction is typically found in Eastern New England, isn't it weird that an American newspaper editor allowed its journalist to get away with a similar colloquial structure, particularly a form with which not every American is familiar? The OP doesn't mention which newspaper, nor where exactly he read it, but I thought American journalists were more "careful" about sort of thing. Would that type of writing be acceptable in a national newspaper?

Comment: My first thought it was a variation on the title of the song 'Je t'aime… moi non plus', which translates as 'I love you… me neither'.

On second thoughts, it could be implying that Keating voted against McGovern because that's what Keating always does.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: the newspaper is talking about a Massachusetts congressman; it's probably a New England newspaper. I am surprised that it got through, but I assume the editor and the journalist were both from New England, and didn't notice the colloquialism. This would probably not happen in a national newspaper.

Answer (score 1):

This is common usage in Maine. Think of it as a rhetorical question. "Jimmy did his homework. And so did not also his brother do his homework?"

Meaning, "You will not be surprised to hear that his brother also did his homework."

Answer (score 0):

N0 "Jimmy did his homework and so didn't his brother" is not correct.  As you thought, it  should be "and so did his brother".  It might help you to see that it is wrong if you rephrase it as " and his brother did also".  "...and his brother didn't also" is incorrect.